# Android activity startActivityForResult not being called

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, kotlin

I am trying to get a file and pass that file to Firebase and store it in my storage bucket but for some reason my startActivityForResult isn't being called even after adding the attribute `android:launchMode="singleTop"` to the manifest file as suggested in another answer and also not using the kotlin static function call on my button click event that is supposed to start the intent. And note both are in the same activity!

Here is my button click handler:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
   btnImage.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent()
            intent.action = Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT
            // set the intent type
            intent.type = "image/*"
            // accept only local content
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true)
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Insert Picture"), PICTURE_RESULT)
        } 
}
```

And this is my startAtivityForResult function:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
//        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (resultCode == PICTURE_RESULT && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (data != null) {
                val imageUri : Uri = data.data!!
                val ref : StorageReference = FirebaseUtil.storageRef!!.child(imageUri.lastPathSegment!!)
                ref.putFile(imageUri)

               {


            } else {
                Log.d("IMAGE", resultCode.toString())
                Toast.makeText(this, "Upload failure", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: you are using fragment or activity?

Comment: activity, is what i am using

Comment: Can you check once resultCode and request code and PICTURE_RESULT values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Android activity startActivityForResult not being called

You need to call `super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)` inside `onActivityResult`

You have commented the code of your `super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)` inside `onActivityResult`

Remove **`//`** from your `super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)` inside `onActivityResult`

Also, Use this

```
 if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == PICTURE_RESULT)
```

insread of this

```
if (resultCode == PICTURE_RESULT && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
```

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == PICTURE_RESULT) {
            if (data != null) {
                val imageUri : Uri = data.data!!
                val ref : StorageReference = FirebaseUtil.storageRef!!.child(imageUri.lastPathSegment!!)
                ref.putFile(imageUri)

               {


            } else {
                Log.d("IMAGE", resultCode.toString())
                Toast.makeText(this, "Upload failure", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Compare PICTURE_RESULT with result code or request code?

Comment: @NarenderReddy Compare `PICTURE_RESULT` with `requestCode

Comment: How on earth I missed that let me change and revert :-(!

Comment: it catches that function now

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen happy to hear that

Answer (score 1):

Change resultCode == PICTURE_RESULT to:
requestCode == PICTURE_RESULT in your if statement.

Comment: Changing that line works.?No need of  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)?

Comment: How on earth I missed that let me change and revert :-(!

Comment: it catches that function now